# why is it necessary to drop and re-create dependents when altering locking scheme in Sybase?

Tags: sybase, recompile

I need to alter the locking scheme from allpages to datarows in a Sybase ASE 15.7 database. The docs says I need to drop and then re-create dependent compiled objects (SPs, triggers, views).

This table has lots of dependent SPs and triggers. My question is, why is this needed, and why an sp_recompile tablename would not be sufficient.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Allpages and (datarows|datapages) schemes have a completely different layout on disk. Changing from one type to the other requires the whole table to be rewritten.

Internally the table is handled completely differently. Allpages is the oldest type available till ASE 11.9.2. Datarows and datapages are new types. Currently most of the new functionality is available only for datarows locking scheme. This leaves the allpages scheme to be obsolete and not any more recommended.

Actually you would create another new copy of the table when you are changing the locking type.

Comment: I understand all this, I'm just curious about why a sp_recompile is not sufficient. With my current understanding, I cannot see technical justification for dropping a re-registering the procedures/triggers